# AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS too long

Tags: authentication, validation, passwords

the 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator', is too long (83 > 79 characters)

I dont know how to slide it without breaking it

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
**'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',**
},
{
'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]

I want to reduce it to 79 characters

Comment: `# noqa: E501`, I suppose.